# How Many Edits Until CW?

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

So I did 4 edits according to the history, and it seems like I am not getting rep for it anymore, and I haven't hit the daily cap yet.

So is it 4 edits by self before it Comes CW?  Maybe I did more, but only little grammar things right after the post I think.... Not entirely sure, I do that a lot :-)

So how many edits by self, others, mix..? What are the actual rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see if a post becomes community wiki - it'll say so in the normal way.

If you're not getting rep for it, have you perhaps hit the daily cap without realising it? There are some times where it doesn't *look* like you've hit the cap, but the internal counter (or whatever) thinks you've hit it. This is particularly true if any posts which have scored you points during the day have been deleted. (For example, I'm currently on 225 for the day on SO despite having 3 accepted answers after hitting the rep cap - the effective rep cap is 180 for me today.)

If you go to the reputation part of the recent activity tab (via the envelope icon, not your user profile) what does that show for the post in question? It should show the number of votes received and the reputation gained.

Comment: Its this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/53360/how-to-get-all-running-process-ids-only  .  It shows 6 Upvotes + Accepted answer, no down votes(according to my rep graph), and 39 rep earned.  Then there is 15 for the it being the accepted answer in another box.  So, must be a post was deleted.  So I guess the moral is not to help people with an answer if I think it might be deleted ;-)  Somehow my most popular answers always seem to get the votes after I hit the cap :-)

Comment: Yup, my Reputation Tracker show 54 rep total too for that answer. So yes, it seems likely that it's a matter of hitting the cap due to deleted/migrated answers.

Comment: 39 rep for 6 upvotes = you definitely hit the rep cap.

Comment: You have a link to this tracker?  I am starting to get addicted to this rep too ;-)  Thanks for the answer by the way...

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you personally edit ten times, the post goes CW. If five different people (i.e. you and four others) edit a post, the post goes CW.

> [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/131713)

It is pretty obvious when something becomes CW, you can see it where your avatar/user card would be on a normal post.

Comment: It's not 6. I've done 8 on numerous times, and once I went past 10 revisions without CW... I got it on 12. Is there an update on this number?

Comment: This answer and its source were outdated, so I edited. I don't typically edit answers to change content, but in this case the OP is unable to make the change himself.

Comment: @PopularDemand The suspension ends in two days, you could have waited then asked him to update.  ;-P

Comment: Yeah, like I would have remembered this after two days, @AdamDavis.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be 6, but the engine will merge multiple edits (by the same person) and hide them from you.

[Here is proof](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/623213/list).

I don't know if this is a bug. It does leave the system open to gaming.