# Threshold for turning posts to CW Mode, on 8th revision or 9th?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1178982/revisions) post, on 9th revision (8 edits), it turns into CW (2009 Jul)

but [this](https://superuser.com/posts/128131/revisions) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2522226/revisions) one, looks like happens on 8th revision (7 edits). (2010 March and April)

So, What is the Threshold for turning posts to CW Mode now? on 8th revision (7 edits)? or how about different person edits, same? Is it different on meta?

PS: the "edits" I mean is **revisions** (The revision number shown on revisions page)

Comment: i thought it was more like twice that.  maybe there were multiple 5-min-window-edits that are shown as one revision but count as individual edits for CW purposes?

Comment: Ah, I should have said 8 revisions or 9

Comment: There is similar questions here - [How Many Edits Until CW?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/how-many-edits-until-cw) but its more like edits by different persons, and 6 is not correct one for own edits

Comment: well, the [other](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits) [refs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/how-many-edits-until-cw) seem to say "6", which is clearly wrong (or outdated).  i just have a memory of it being more like 12-14 edits, but maybe that was including non-owner edits.

Comment: May be I will verify again on this post. everyone - please don't edit for a few minutes, may be 20 or 25 minutes. I need to do few more edits.

Comment: Another [data point](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1984213/revisions) from '10 February puts it at 10 edits.  (Note one by another user, a moderator, and none were retag-only.)

Comment: @Gnome, thanks, looks like something changed between Feb and March then.

Comment: Ah, threshold on Questions and Answers could be different also. someone please test that on answer too.

Comment: The thresholds on Meta could be different from SOFU :]

Comment: I see, Looks like its 9 for Questions, or may be only on meta.

Comment: @S.Mark: I do not want to confuse you, but these are 8 edits. First one is no edit.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer, I should have mentioned that I meant revision numbers show on revision page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the FAQ, [What are Community Wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741), states:

> The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
>
> The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

The answer is then ***ten edits*** (if only the OP has made edits, that's  ***11 items in the revision list*** as the initial post is not counted as an edit). But the implementation appears to be out of sync with this specification as in "[Difference between URI and URL](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1984213/revisions)" (Gnome's datapoint, 9 edits by the OP and 2 edits by two other users [12 items in the revision list]).

Comment: Looks like its 9 for Questions, or may be only on meta

Comment: @S.Mark: isn't it 8? The first edit has number 2 in the revision list. The initial post should not count as an edit.

Comment: sorry for wrong usage of "edits" i meant the revisions [numbers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/46015/revisions) show on revision pages.

Comment: if initial post couldn't count as edits, two examples on my questions will be 7 edits.

Comment: Note that my example does follow what you said (8 edits by OP plus 1 misc., yielding CW on revision 10), it just doesn't follow the later examples S.Mark gave.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).

Answer (score 1):

CW after 21<sub>4</sub> revisions, or 1,000 edits by the original author.

Comment: thanks for the test, I hope people wont mind with our edits. :-)

Comment: looks like 9 revisions on meta, if your next edits goes CW. but 8 on others (just guess, since we cannot thest it)

Comment: View revision history if 1,000 doesn't make sense, and shame on you.

Comment: @Peter, if so, two examples on my questions will be 7 edits.

Comment: @SMark: Know if any edits in your examples got [merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/how-many-edits-until-cw/14105#14105)?

Comment: @Gnome, don't you think that question's revisions is something different? its says Post Made Community Wiki by Community♦ and happens 12 minutes after last edits. and why do you think there is more than 4 revisions and its got merged? if there is more than 4 revisions, the only I **can** think of, is moderators deleted some revisions manually.

Comment: @Gnome, I forgot to answer your question, [second](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2522226/revisions) one in my examples is mine, I don't think merging happens on that post (its 9 days ago, I think I still remember :D)

Comment: @SMark: I was thinking the same about the example he gave, noticing the timestamps, so it doesn't represent proof to me. But I thought the edit-merging could've still played a factor.