# How many edits until answer turns to CW?

Tags: support, community-wiki, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
>   [Threshold for turning posts to CW Mode, on 8th revision or 9th?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46008/threshold-for-turning-posts-to-cw-mode-on-8th-revision-or-9th)

There's a few similar questions around here. Most of them suggest the answer is

- Six edits by four different people, or
- Eight edits by the original poster

But [in a recent answer of mine I made ten edits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/23759/revisions), and the answer is still not a community wiki.

Comment: You only made 9 edits.  Try it again and see if that does it.  There are 10 revisions, but only 9 edits to the original version.

Comment: One of your edits was probably inside the grace period; when you first post you have a few minutes to edit without it counting as an "edit" (so you don't clog up revision history I guess)

Comment: You might be counting the initial post as an "edit". I see only 9... oops; I see @AdamDavis already said that. D'oh! (on mobile; can't delete)

Comment: If you link to the questions that say six/eight, I'll go try to fix them.

Comment: @PopularDemand **(1)**  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46015/162042 **(2)** http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14095/162042

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The FAQ question on Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) states that a post will be made CW if;

- The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
- The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

... and a few other reasons, which aren't relevant to your question.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).